# Recursive SQL query with Ecto.Query

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

I have a `categories` table with the following columns:

```
id
name
parent_id (nullable)
```

And a `books` table which has a `category_id` column inside of it.
I want a function that takes a list of category ids (`category_ids`) and returns a query that gets books which belong to one of the given categories or their children (recursive).

I've already written a query that returns all of a given category's children. I could use that to fetch all of the subcategories of `category_ids` categories and use the new list. But it would send several queries to the database and I want to do it in one query. Here's the query:

```
with recursive cat_tree as (
  select id,
    name,
    parent_id
  from categories
  where id = $1
  union all
  select child.id, 
    child.name,
    child.parent_id
  from categories as child
  join cat_tree as parent on parent.id = child.parent_id
)
select *
from cat_tree;
```

**EDITED**

```
  @raw_sql """
  select id,
    name,
    parent_id
  from categories
  where id in (?)
  union all
    select child.id,
           child.name,
           child.parent_id
  from categories as child
    join cat_tree as parent on parent.id = child.parent_id
  """

  def category_search_query(query, []), do: query 
  def category_search_query(query, category_ids) do
    query
    |> recursive_ctes(true)
    |> with_cte("cat_tree", as: fragment(@raw_sql, ^category_ids))
    |> join(:inner, [b], c in "cat_tree", on: c.id == b.category_id)
  end
```

But when I pass `[12, 13]` (for example) to the function, it gives me the following error:

```
(DBConnection.EncodeError) Postgrex expected an integer in -9223372036854775808..9223372036854775807, got '\f\r'. Please make sure the value you are passing matches the definition in your table or in your query or convert the value accordingly.
```

But when I pass just an integer (and not a list), it works correctly.

Comment: seems like you just need to join result of your cte with books table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a procedure to get list of categories as parameter (can be an array) and change your query to this :

```
create function funcName (categoryIds int[])
returns table ( bookid int ,categoryid int , ...<deffine book columns>)
as 
$$ 
with recursive cat_tree as (
    select
        id,name,parent_id
    from
        categories
    where id in (select unnest(categoryIds))
    union all
    select
        child.id,child.name,child.parent_id
    from
        categories as child
    join cat_tree as parent on parent.id = child.parent_id
)
select
    b.*
from
    cat_tree c
join books on c.id = b.categoryid
$$ Language sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is the right answer but I just don't know how to pass my `category_ids` list through ecto's fragment. I'll edit the question to include it.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found the answer. Just had to replace with `where id in (?)` with `where id = ANY (?)`